# Function from chrome alarm executes twice in extension background.js

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Note: This is my first time ever writing an extension, and using alarms/notifications.

I wanted to learn by myself how to make extensions and use alarms/notifications, and i got to the point, where my extension runs in the background, periodically checking for test notifications on a test local server, and displays any that are present. The problem is, that after the initial check, every next one is called twice, which means that every other one appears for a split-second and is overwritten.
Here's the 'code' (content.js is empty for now):

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Bruh",
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
    "permissions": [
        "http://127.0.0.1/",
        "alarms",
        "notifications"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://127.0.0.1/taikoThingy/users.php"
            ],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
}
```

**background.js**

```
var audio = new Audio('./audio.mp3');

function checkForNotifications() {

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // an xhr request to a test server to look for notifications
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var result = this.responseText; // json containing notification data

            if (result != " ") {
                result = JSON.parse(result);
                chrome.notifications.create("whatever", {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "iconUrl": "./icon.png",
                    "title": `${result.notif_type}`,
                    "message": `${result.notif_text}`
                }, function notifId() {});
                audio.play();
            }
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", 'http://127.0.0.1/taikoThingy/test.php');
    xhttp.send();

}

chrome.alarms.create("notifAlarm", {"delayInMinutes":0.01, "periodInMinutes": 1});

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function alarm() {
    checkForNotifications();
});
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

    require 'server.php';

    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM tab_notifications ORDER BY id ASC"); // get the oldest notification
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo '{ "notif_type":"' . $row['notif_type'] . '",'; // set the received data as JSON
        echo '"notif_text":"' . $row['notif_text'] . '"}';
        $stmt = $link->prepare("DELETE FROM tab_notifications ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute(); // delete that entry
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        echo " ";
    }

?>
```

What's causing the double execution? What should i fix? I couldn't find a working solution :c

Comment: Check in the Inspector tools > network what requests are sent and tell us.